# How to generate a matrix of frequency of consecutive characters from txt file in java?

Tags: java, file, frequency

I have a large txt file(2GB). I read the whole txt file character by character to find out the frequency of each character in the whole txt file using the following code snippet.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(file),
                        Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        int c;
        while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
            char ch = (char) c;
            // rest of the code
        }
```

Now I need to generate a matrix with the frequency of consecutive characters.
For example, how many times a character 'b' exists after character 'a'(consecutive,immediate character) and vice versa.

Suppose, I have a input string(from the file) :  **cad bed abed dada**

The frequency matrix, would be like
[Please click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFjgT.png)

How to do this? Will appreciate any help and suggestion. 
Thank you.

Comment: Why is b after a only once marked in that image? There are 2 b's following 2 a's

Comment: @Cratylus sorry you may get it wrong. Here, only the word 'abed' has a 'b' after 'a'.  I said consecutive. Hope this helps. Anyway I think you understood what I want. Thank you.

Comment: Yes in `abed` there is 1 `b` after an `a`. But your input string is not `abed` but `cad bed abed dada`

Comment: Is it per word? Not in the whole input?

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the last character read. if lastchar=='' continue. use a Map to store the values.you can then loop over the combinations and pull the value from the map , or you could address a 2d array directly by subtracting the int value for char 'a' from the current character pairs.

```
    Map<String, Integer> table = new HashMap<>();
    String last = "";
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (last.isEmpty()) {
            last = String.format("%c", c);
            continue;
        }
        String thing = last + c;
        Integer count = table.getOrDefault(thing, 0);
        table.put(thing, count + 1);
        last = String.format("%c", c);
    }
```

Comment: How to keep track of last character? I have tried but it's been overlapping with new character since it is in a loop(code in my question). Please help.